# Basic calculus question about interior points of a set.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, general-topology

Let Let $X = \{ (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : 1 \leq \sqrt{x^2 + y^2} < 2 \} $. I want to show $ \{ (x,y) : 1 < \sqrt{x^2+y^2} < 2 \} = D$ is the interior of $X$.  Consider, $f(x,y) = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2} $. Since $f$ is continuous, then $f^{-1}(1,2) = D$ is open. and since $D \subset X$, then $D \subseteq Int X$. How can I show that $Int X \subseteq D $ ?

MY attempt:

Suppose $p \notin D$. then we have either

$||p|| <1$   or

$||p|| > 2 $

Suppose $||p|| < 1 $. We want to show $p \notin Int X$. Suppose on the contrary that there exists some $r > 0$ such that $B(p,r) \subseteq X$. Hence

$1 \leq ||p|| < 1 \implies 1 < 1.  $
contradiction. Similarly we have a contradiction if we suppose the second case holds.
hence, in any case, $p$ cannot be in the interior of $X$.

Is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's correct, but a little sloppy. The word "Hence" is slightly misused. I'd say "Suppose for some $r > 0$ that $B(p, r) \subset X$. Then $q = (1 - \frac{r}{2})p$ is in the ball, but $\| q \| = 1 - \frac{r}{2} < 1$; that's a contradiction.

In general, there's a lot to be said for exhibiting a *specific* point that has some property than making a general statement -- it's harder to argue against specific evidence. :)

Comment: why $q = (1 - \frac{r}{2})p$ is in the ball ?

Comment: It's in the ball because it's distance $r/2$ from $p$, and the ball $B(p, r)$ has radius $r$.